# Run a jquery script in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension that needs to send a POST http request. I have a short jquery script that sends the post request, but I am currently stuck at getting the extension to run the script when the browser action button is clicked. I have read through several other similar scenarios here, but none have seemed to work for me.

here is the script (saved as send.js):

```
var URL = "https://api.pushjet.io/message"
var data = "secret=*my api key*&message=test&title=test1&level=5&link=https://youtube.com"


$.post(URL,data);
```

here is the manifest I am currently using:

```
{
 "name": "plugin name",
 "version": "0",
 "description": "What do I do as an extension",
 "background": {"page": "background.html"},
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "browser_action": {
   "name": "Manipulate DOM",
   "icons": ["icon.png"],
   "default_icon": "icon.png"
 },
 "content_scripts": [ {
   "js": [ "jquery.min.js", "background.js" ],
   "css": ["customStyles.css"],
   "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
 }]
}
```

and here is the background.js

```
// this is the background code...

// listen for our browerAction to be clicked
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    // for the current tab, inject the "inject.js" file & execute it
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
        file: 'send.js'
    });
});
```

thanks much

Comment: I suggest you use native `XMLHttpRequest` or native `fetch` instead of requiring a bloated slow library to do a simple `POST`

Comment: The [extension architecture article](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) will explain the basics you need to know to write an extension. As for the problem, you need to declare a background/event page in the manifest, not `content_scripts` (see the docs link). Then take a look at [activeTab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) permission.